# How can I set default permission with ACL in linux?

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions, acl

I have two groups `group1` and `group2`.

I need `group1` users to be able to read-write (rwx) files owned by users in `group2`, but users in `group2` cannot write to (r-x) files from `group1`.

All users in a group can read, but not write to, files on the same group (r-x)

I know that I can use ACL (Access Control Lists) to deal with it.

```
setfacl -m g:group1:rwx "directory owned by a group2 user"
```

the problem is that it must be set for every new folder. is there a way to set as default so that every new `group2 user's` file/folder have this permission applied?

will this default be applied if I create a new user in `group2`?

I know that the normal permissions are copied from `/etc/skel` to the home folder when a new user is created, but how to make the acl permissions to be copied too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For default permissions its "-d". So you can use this:

```
setfacl -d -m g:group1:rwx "Main directory owned by group2 user"
```

Also do check the *effective rights* with getfacl. You may have to set the mask also.

Comment: Why does `-d -m` work and `-m -d` cause "setfacl: Option -m: Invalid argument near character 1"?

Answer (score -1):

You don't need ACLs.

Put all users from group1 also into group2. Then ensure you put the setgid bit the directories: all new files will owned by the directory owner, with similar permissions (setgid will be added to new subdirs).

```
# Setup as root
mkdir -p /tmp/test/1
chgrp group1 /tmp/test/1
chmod g+wsx,o= /tmp/test/1
mkdir -p /tmp/test/2
chgrp group2 /tmp/test/2
chmod g+ws,o= /tmp/test/2
# user1 is in groups users (primary gid), group1, group2 
# user2 is in groups users (primary gid), group2
# as user1:users
mkdir -p /tmp/test/{1,2}/d1
touch /tmp/test/{1,2}/{f1,d1/f1}
# as user2:users
mkdir -p /tmp/test/{1,2}/d2
touch /tmp/test/{1,2}/{f2,d2/f2}
# check the ownerships on everything
ls -la /tmp/test/{1,2}/{f{1,2},d{1,2},d{1,2}/f{1,2}}
```

If you do want to stick with ACLs, you need to look at default ACLs, you do similar to the above with them.

As for adding new users and `/etc/skel/`, I'm afraid you're out of luck there, the stock `useradd` command does not preserve any ACLs or xattrs when copying /etc/skel/.